# Clear call stack whenever props changes in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux

While trying to execute the code below with type = "ABC" initially, my props suddenly changed to type = "XYZ" before the complete execution of lazyLoad function(since window was not completely loaded at that time). Result : 
XYZ
hello
in lazyLoad
ABC
ABC

I don't want my lazyload function to execute if my props are changed. What should i do?

Code Snippet

```
class Type extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        type : props.type
    }
    if(__CLIENT__ && this.state.type == "ABC"){
        let self = this;
        window.onload = function(e) {
            self.lazyLoad(props.type);
        }

        }
    }


componentDidMount(){
        if(this.state.type != "ABC") {
                this.someFunction();
        }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.type !== this.state.type){
            if(nextProps.type != "ABC") {
                this.someFunction();
            }
        this.setState({
            type : nextProps.type
        });
    }
}


someFunction(){
    console.log(this.state.type);
    //some other logic as well
    this.someFunction1();

}

lazyLoad(type) {
    if(type == this.state.type){
        console.log("in lazyLoad");
        console.log(type);
        console.log(this.state.type);
        this.someFunction1();
    }
}

someFunction1(){
    console.log("hello");
}


render() {
    //some code logic
}
```

}

Comment: What's the technical reason to call `window.onload` in the constructor of the component?

Comment: If you don't want to run `lazyLoad` when certain criteria are met, wrap the call to `lazyLoad` in an `if` statement (*not* the call to `window.onload`).

Comment: I want lazyload function to call only when my page is loaded completely, but if the user clicks on proceed button before the page was loaded completely, my props get changed and i don't want the execution of lazyload anymore in this scenario.

Comment: @lux Please help further.